# Power Bi clustered column chart with multiple sorting

Tags: powerbi

I have a clustered column chart in power bi. I have a measure as a value. I have years as legend. I want to order the value by the highest value of the highest year and ignore the other years.
For example (let’s call my measure IPTV)

```
Level1   | Year | IPTV
---------|------|-----
Actuator | 2019 | 0.5
Actuator | 2018 | 4.5
Seal     | 2019 | 1.5
Seal     | 2018 | 2.5
```

I want seal first as it has highest value for 2019 at this point I don’t care what the value of 2018 is.
I have year in legend. And IPTV in value and level2 in Axis.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I thought I knew what you wanted, but after reading your example I get a different understanding of the goal.  Is it correct to say that you want to sort Level1 in descending order of the most recent year's IPTV value?

Comment: The highest value of IPTV for the most recent year. My understanding is that it sum all the values of IPTV for individual level 2 and order it by them. In the example above it will order it by Actuator as the sum of IPTV is 5. Now I am wondering if I have to use custom control not sure which one can do it.Thank you for looking into it though.

Comment: I think it's not very elegant, but you could just create 'year' measures for each year like this:  2019IPTV = CALCULATE([IPTV], Table[Year] = "2019")... and pull those one at a time into the Values of a clustered bar with Level1 on your axis.  You'd be able to sort on 2019ITPV descending then.  Kind of a pain if you have lots of years though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the measure you have to create
2019IPTV = CALCULATE([Level2IPTV]| FILTER(YearsNew|YearsNew[years]=max(YearsNew[Years])))
and then drag it to "tooltips" and that will fix the issue. Microsoft "help desk " cant figure it out. Thanks to Ryan I was able to.